# Running my app in background

Tags: android, background

I want to check, my program is in background or not! my prgram have one package(all of my classes is in one package). I searched and finally i found this way. i write this code but when my program is in background, my code not run. why?

```
public class BackgroundCheck extends AsyncTask<Context,Void,Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Context context=arg0[0];
        return isAppInBackground(context);
    }

    private boolean isAppInBackground(Context context){
        ActivityManager activityManager=(ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcess=activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcess==null)
            return false;
        final String packageName=context.getPackageName();

        Log.e("packageName", packageName);
        //Toast.makeText(context, "packageName="+packageName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for(RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo:appProcess){
            if((processInfo.importance==RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND)&&( processInfo.processName.equals(packageName))){
                Log.e("process", "in background");
                Toast.makeText(context, "process in background", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("packagenmae", processInfo.processName);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and i add this code in this class but when my program in background, else if was run ! like always my program is in foreground ! what is problem??

```
if((processInfo.importance==RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND)&&( processInfo.processName.equals(packageName))){
    Log.e("process", "in background");
    Toast.makeText(context, "process in background", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("packagenmae", processInfo.processName);
    return true;
}
else if((processInfo.importance==RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FORGROUND)&&( processInfo.processName.equals(packageName))){
    Log.e("process","in forground");
    return true;
}
```

Can i use another way that run in api 7+? That way should be reliable... 
Thanks for advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know that your app is in background or not then you have to use **Service** for that

you should go with this:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Only one activity can run at a time. All others are suspended when another activity becomes active.

If you want code to run reliably in the background you would need to use a service.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.what do you mean of Service? how can i create a service for checking this ?

Comment: and another thing, i konw, i can run one activity at a time but for checking that my program is in background or nut, Should not check this with package name? this is wrong?

Comment: If I had code that needed to be run only when my app was not active then I would run a service. My activity could communicate with the service and notify it when in the foreground. It could also notify the service before suspending therefore the service would know the activity is no longer in the foreground. It really depends on what you are doing and why you are doing it.